# Cannot dismiss view using self.presentation.wrappedValue.dismiss() when using navigationview in swfitui

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

First of all, before you link another stack overflow post using something like modal, I already tried but couldn't implement it because of the foreach. my contentview code looks like this:

```
NavigationView{
        
        ScrollView{
            
            
            Group{
                VStack{
                    //just the current stuff
                    Text("Current Forecast")
                    Text("condition: \(f.responses.current.condition?.text ?? "Loading...")")
                    Text("temp: \(Int(Double.rounded(f.responses.current.temp_f)())) degrees fahrenheit")
                }
                .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 30, height: 120, alignment: .center)
                .background(Color.gray.opacity(0.8))
                .cornerRadius(20)
                .foregroundColor(.black)
                .font(.system(size: 18).bold())
                .opacity(0.4)
                
                //iterates through the hours of the day
                
                ScrollView(.horizontal){
                    LazyHStack {
                        ForEach(0..<f.responses.forecast.forecastday[0].hour.count){index in
                            NavigationLink(destination: detailedView(info: f.responses.forecast.forecastday[0].hour[index])
                                            .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
                                            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all),
                                           label:  {listView(h: f.responses.forecast.forecastday[0].hour[index]).frame(width: 90, height: 100, alignment: .center).background(Color.gray).opacity(0.4).cornerRadius(20)})
                            
                            
                            
                        }
                    }
                    
                }.navigationBarHidden(true)
            }
            
            
            
            
        }.navigationBarHidden(true).background(
            Group{
                //checks if it is night
                if (timeToInt(f.responses.location.localtime) < 19 && timeToInt(f.responses.location.localtime) > 5){
                    Image("\(f.responses.current.condition?.code ?? 1000)")
                        .resizable()
                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                    
                    //if it is night, uses a different image
                }else{
                    Image("night")
                        .resizable()
                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                }
            }
            
        )
        
        
        
        
        
        
    } .background(
        Group{
            //checks if it is night
            if (timeToInt(f.responses.location.localtime) < 19 && timeToInt(f.responses.location.localtime) > 5){
                Image("\(f.responses.current.condition?.code ?? 1000)")
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                
                //if it is night, uses a different image
            }else{
                Image("night")
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
            }
        }
        
    )
```

Meanwhile my "detailedview" code looks like this:

```
import SwiftUI

struct detailedView: View {
    var info : Hour
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    
    public var body: some View {
        let rawTime = info.time
        
        
        
        //rounding
        let displayTemp_F = Int(Double.rounded(info.temp_f)())
        let displayFeelslike_f = Int(Double.rounded(info.feelslike_f)())
        let displayWind_mph = Int(Double.rounded(info.wind_mph)())
        GeometryReader{geo in
            
            
            VStack{
                Button(action: {
                            self.dismissSelf()
                        }) {
                            Text("Dismiss Me!")
                        }
                Spacer()
                Group{
                    
                    //displaying all the data
                    Text(info.condition?.text ?? "API error")
                    Text("Time: \(String(rawTime[rawTime.lastIndex(of: " ")!...]))")
                    Text("Temperature: \(displayTemp_F) degrees fahrenheit")
                    Text("Feels like: \(displayFeelslike_f) degrees fahrenheit")
                    Text("Wind MPH: \(displayWind_mph)")
                }
                .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 30, height: 50, alignment: .center)
                .background(Color.white.opacity(0.5))
                .cornerRadius(20)
                .foregroundColor(.black)
                .font(.system(size: 18).bold())
                //all of the . stuff are for making the text look nice
                
                
                Spacer()
                Spacer()
                Spacer()
            } //making things look nice
            .frame(width: geo.size.width, height: geo.size.height, alignment: .top)
            .background(
                Group{
                    
                    if (timeToInt(info.time) < 19 && timeToInt(info.time) > 5){
                        Image("\(info.condition?.code ?? 1000)")
                            .resizable()
                            .scaledToFill()
                            .frame(width: geo.size.width, height: geo.size.height, alignment: .top)
                    }else{
                        Image("night")
                            .resizable()
                            .scaledToFill()
                            .frame(width: geo.size.width, height: geo.size.height, alignment: .top)
                    }
                    
                }
                
            )
            
        }.frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height, alignment: .top)
    }
    
    private func dismissSelf() {
            presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
        }
    
}
```

**PLEASE DO NOT LINK ANOTHER STACK OVERFLOW POST UNLESS YOU ARE SURE IT IS RELATED! THE LAST COUPLE QUESTIONS I ASKED HAD PEOPLE LINKING UNRELATED POSTS!**

sorry for that. I am basically just trying to create a "back" button that doesn't blend in with the background. I also do not want a back button that takes up the entire top bar. Any help would be appreciated!

I also just found out about .toolbar, and I'm not sure if I could use that to put a custom back button up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by simply setting the back button to invisible and putting an image behind it. I added this code:

```
class Theme {
    static func navigationBarColors(background : UIColor?,
                                    titleColor : UIColor? = nil, tintColor : UIColor? = nil ){
        
        let navigationAppearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
        navigationAppearance.configureWithOpaqueBackground()
        navigationAppearance.backgroundColor = background ?? .black
        
        navigationAppearance.titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: titleColor ?? .black]
        navigationAppearance.largeTitleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: titleColor ?? .black]
        
        UINavigationBar.appearance().standardAppearance = navigationAppearance
        UINavigationBar.appearance().compactAppearance = navigationAppearance
        UINavigationBar.appearance().scrollEdgeAppearance = navigationAppearance
        
        UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = tintColor ?? titleColor ?? .black
    }
}
```

it allows me to change the back button. I then added this:

```
init(){
           Theme.navigationBarColors(background: .clear, titleColor: .clear)
        }
```

This got added to contentview struct, and makes the back button invisible. Far from the best way to do it, but it is simple.